# Python path issue with django

Tags: python, django

In centos 6.7 python 2.6 is pre installed. I installed django==1.7.0.
But while running server i am getting a issue:

```
python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

After that i installed python2.7. I just need to know is there any way so that i ll set the path of python version in manage.py

May be any lead to find out the solution.
anyone having any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using `virtualenv`? If so, did you activate it?

Comment: yes. But how to change the setting in manage.py

Comment: Just make sure you installed django while your virtualenv is activated(look at `pip freeze` output). At last you could also try `<path-to-virtualenv-python> manage.py runserver`.

Comment: after running server in venv i am also getting same error

Comment: yeah. i removed & again installed.Now works but i am getting other errors

Comment: @Shang Wang....Is there any way without activating virtual environment ijust change some settings in manage.py so that it ll take care of everything Like: which version of Python path will it include & if proper version is not installed it ll install automatically through some command & all rest things as well

Comment: I mean to say just think of changing manage.py

Comment: I'd rather add what you just said in the `activate` script for virtualenv, so when you `source` the script it does everything.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using the correct python version where you installed django.

You can check your python versions on system with command:

```
ls /usr/local/lib | grep python
```

normaly if you don't have more than 1 instalation of python 2 and one of python3 pip installs on python2 and pip3 installs on python3

you can set the new virtualenv by setting the path of python you want to use

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 <project_name>
```

If you are using Django 1.7 you probably want to use

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```